# Fabric deploying application to a proxyed server

Tags: python, django, deployment, fabric, automated-deploy

I would like to deploy an application using fabric to a proxied server. Normally we ssh to a proxy server then ssh to the production server, however fabric doesn’t seem to allow for this directly.

An example of the setup would be local --> server A (Proxy) --> Server B (App server)

The destination is server B.

I have tried using the fab file below to test.

```
import os.path
from fabric.api import env, run, sudo, cd, local, put, settings
from fabric.contrib.files import sed, exists
from datetime import datetime

def proxy():
    env.user = "root"
    env.hosts = ['proxy']
    env.key_filename = "/home/root/monitorserver.pem"

def production():
    """Defines production environment ."""
    env.is_debuggable = False
    env.user = "root"
    env.hosts = ['appserver']
    env.key_filename = "/home/root/appserver.pem"

def createfile():
    """Start Excecute test commands"""
    sudo("touch /tmp/test_%s" % datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

but running the commands

```
fab proxy createfile production createfile
```

only seems to work as

```
fab proxy createfile
fab production createfile
```

Is there a way I can run fabric locally and deploy to server B with the proxy in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done by creating 2 fabfiles: 1 on local, and 1 on the proxy server.

```
from fabric.api import env, run, sudo, cd
from datetime import datetime

def proxy():
    env.user = "root"
    env.hosts = ['proxy']
    env.key_filename = "/home/root/monitorserver.pem"
    with cd('/home/root/'):
        createfile()
        run("fab production")

def production():
    """Defines production environment ."""
    env.is_debuggable = False
    env.user = "root"
    env.hosts = ['appserver']
    env.key_filename = "/home/root/appserver.pem"
    createfile()

def createfile():
    """Start Excecute test commands"""
    sudo("touch /tmp/test_%s" % datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

Run `fab proxy`.

(Haven't tested the code, but something like this should work.)

Comment: Thanks @Pratyush I ended up doing just that.